# Using SageMaker Debugger and Debugger Profiler with custom containers (BYOC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, containers, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

I see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/debugger-bring-your-own-container.html that is is possible to user the **SageMaker Debugger** and the **Debugger profiler** with **custom containers**, but it seems to only be usable if you are using the SageMaker estimator.

Can SageMaker Debugger and the profiler be used with custom containers when the SageMaker estimator is not being used? We technically use the SageMaker estimator, but that estimator is just a wrapper for a Java application. Can the SageMaker Debugger and the profiler be used in that context?